# Using lpr to print a file whose path has spaces

Tags: bash, python, lpr

So my path:

`/Users/work/Desktop/My Folder/My File.txt`

My Folder and My File have spaces. Of course, in Terminal, when you tab for autocompletion it would do `/Users/work/Desktop/My\ Folder/My\ File.txt`.

My problem is when I use that path in python as such:

```
from subprocess import Popen

def print_rc(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as infile:
        p = Popen(["lpr -o page-ranges=1-2"], stdin=infile)
        output = p.communicate()[0]
```

I get an error that `no such file or directory` error. When I do `os.path.exists('/Users/work/Desktop/My Folder/My File.txt')`, it turns out as `True`. So I think the problem has to do with the spaces.

What would I need to do to make convert the python string into something bash can understand then?

Comment: No, that's not why.

Comment: How come I call 'lpr' with that same file directly from the command line but not from Python? My printer prints when on the command line.

Comment: WAIT! `shell=True` needs to be added to the constructor of `Popen`. lol

Comment: Because you're doing it correctly on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.Popen` doesn't want a shell command line. It wants an array of exec arguments:

```
Popen(["lpr", "-o", "page-ranges=1-2"])
```